# How can I focus on a react-select component at will?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Using react-select v2, I want to show and focus on the Select element when the user hits a certain key. Following are some things I've tried or paths I've gone down.

When I set a ref to the Select element and try to call `.focus` on it, it says no focus function is found. Perhaps I should somehow get a child element of it and then call focus on that?

There doesn't seem to be any prop I can pass that will trigger a focus function. There is an `openOnFocus` but not a `focusOnOpen`. The only thing I can think of would be to enable autoFocus and then somehow trigger a remount but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this and it feels hacky. Alternatively, I could enable just create the Select component each time the key is pressed instead of showing it, then unmount it instead of hiding it.

How can I properly get the react-select element to gain focus when I want it to?

I'm using a wrapper component around my  component. Here's the render method for my wrapper:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        options={this.props.options}
        value={this.state.value}
        ref={this.selectRef}
      />
    );
  }
```

And here's where I'm calling that wrapper:

```
        <Wrapper
          options={this.props.labelOptions}
          ref={this.wrapperRef}
        />
```

I then try calling focus using either `this.dropdownNode.focus()` or `this.dropdownNode.current.focus()` and both say no focus method is found.

Comment: `react-select` has a focus function on it's ref, can you show us how you tried it?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings ah in that case it could be because I'm implementing a wrapper component over it. So I need to expose the focus function. I'll try that and then post code if it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like the react-select autoFocus attribute is calling `.focus()` on the inputRef as seen here: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/Select.js#L471

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're wrapping the `Select` component, you can't call Select's `.focus()` function from the ref you're giving to the wrapper. Since `ref` is a special kind of prop, the ref for that wrapper is only referring to `Wrapper` itself, *not* the component it wraps (Select).

To access the actual `Select` component's ref, you have to pass a ref down to it as a prop with a different, non-magic name, like `innerRef` (react-select code actually gives a good example of this as it's accessing the actual input element and [focusing on that](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/Select.js#L471)).

Here's the change that fixed it. Here is the wrapper component where Select is actually used (and it's taking in the ref passed to it):

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        options={this.props.options}
        value={this.state.value}
        ref={this.props.innerRef}
      />
    );
  }
```

And here's the component that's calling that wrapper. In the constructor I'm creating the ref with `this.selectRef = React.createRef()` then I pass it in as a prop in this render method:

```
        <Wrapper
          options={this.props.labelOptions}
          innerRef={this.selectRef}
        />
```

Then I can call focus on the `Select` component itself by running `this.selectRef.current.focus()` anywhere I want to.

**Notes:** Thanks to BoyWithSilverWings answer. This question pertains to React 16.3. There is also a new `React.ForwardRefs` method but this way seems simpler to me.

Comment: I am using React-select v2.4.4. Thing which worked for me was `this.selectRef.focus()`. Maybe it will be useful to someone someday.

Comment: Hi there, do you have a codesandbox example? I'm facing the same problem.