# How to get a ref for an instance of React Select's AsyncCreatable to focus the Select inside it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have seen that `Select` has a `ref` prop that works as it is usual in the React world.

But I have a piece of code that uses it indirectly, through `AsyncCreatable`:

```
<AsyncCreatable>
  {({ default: AsyncCreatableSelect }) => (
    <AsyncCreatableSelect
      ref={this.focusRef}
      className="react-select-container"
      classNamePrefix="react-select"
      defaultOptions={this.props.choices || []}
      styles={customSelectStyles}
      theme={selectTheme}
      components={{ DropdownIndicator, Option }}
      isMulti
      value={selectedOption || []}
      loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      placeholder={this.props.intl.formatMessage(messages.select)}
      noOptionsMessage={() =>
        this.props.intl.formatMessage(messages.no_options)
      }
    />
  )}
</AsyncCreatable>
```

The problem with the above code is that the following line in it does not work:

```js
ref={this.focusRef}
```

The reason I want to use a ref here is that *I want to focus* the `Select`.

How can I do this? I searched the docs of react-select and superficially searched the source code. I think I saw that the Select has a focus method but I do not know how to use it.

I rapidly read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310433/how-can-i-focus-on-a-react-select-component-at-will) but with no use because in that case the `Select` is used directly (not through HOCs such as `AsyncCreatable`).

Thank you.

## Update

I also tried putting the ref on the `AyncCreatable` JSX tag instead of on the `AsyncCreatableSelect`, with no use.